# The infiltrator

Tags: lateral-thinking

The house has two doors and two windows. There's no other way of getting in or out.

There are five people inside the house right now. All of them entered the house through different means:

- Albert entered through one door.
- Becky entered through the other door.
- Charles entered through one window.
- Diana entered through the other window.

How did Eve, the fifth person, get inside the house?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps

> Eve was born in the house.